# F#: Double backticked value names clash with function names?

Tags: f#, backticks

In Visual Studio 2015:

```
let myFunction (``string`` : string) =
    "\"Quoted string\"" |> (Regex "\"[^\"]*\"").Match |> string

let myOtherFunction (str : string) =
    "\"Quoted string\"" |> (Regex "\"[^\"]*\"").Match |> string
```

First function generates a compiler error, the `string` function is underlined in red.  ("This expression was expected to have type Match -> 'a but here has type string")

Second function is fine, no problems.

Is this by design?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The reason is, your parameter and the call at the end are the same thing. Double backticks are used to escape the name, **they are not part of the name**.

So in your case that means that ``` ``string`` ``` and `string` are exactly the same thing, you are trying to pipe into your string parameter. And yes, this is totally by design.

The C# equivalent are @-escaped names, where for example `@hello` and `hello` would clash.

Comment: And, in fact, the double-backticks aren't necessary here at all. You could have written `let upper (string : string) = string.ToUpper()` and it would have worked: `upper "foo"` would produce the result `"FOO"`. The only time the double-backticks are **necessary** is if you want to name your parameter by the name of a keyword like `type`, or if you want to include spaces or other normally-illegal punctuation in its name.